# Unable to connect Postgres with psql

Tags: postgresql

I have checked the server status with `sudo service postgresql status`

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2019-06-11 13:51:09 IST; 15min ago
  Process: 929 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 929 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Jun 11 13:51:07 ISW114 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jun 11 13:51:09 ISW114 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Jun 11 13:56:53 ISW114 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

it working fine but when i try with psql i'm getting error as below

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Well, is it running? Can you see any postgres processes with "ps auxw"? Is there a socket at `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`?

Comment: Hi @RichardHuxton, No, I can't see any postgres process running

Comment: OK, so then you look in the logs (probably /var/log/postgresql/ but also check the system logs)